# What is the verb for "cognition"?

Tags: verbs

Going by known pairs of nouns and verbs, it would be "cognite", but is it valid? If not, what's the right word?

**Update**: I know ***cognise*** or ***cognize***, but it doesn't cover the full meaning of "cognition" as it's used now. E.g., AHD has "The mental process or faculty of knowing, including aspects such as awareness, perception, reasoning, and judgment." Consider the usage in "Cognitive-Behavorial Therapy". It's far more than just the meaning of "know".

Furthermore, ***cognize*** is the verb for ***cognizance***, not cognition.

Comment: Please include an example sentence where you would use the verb form. Have you checked the POS, meaning and usage of *cognite*?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the FAQ. See also [ell.se]

Comment: I've googled: "meaning cognite" and can't find any English meaning. (It's available as Latin and Italian.

Comment: How would you define *cognitive* as in CBT? Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy#Cognitive_therapy_roots

Comment: Kris, that page isn't so useful for this purpose. See this: http://www.gerardkeegan.co.uk/glossary/gloss_c.htm 
You'll find "using our cognitions of perception, attention, language, memory, and thinking".

Comment: Why isn't the verb simply *thinking*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading through, I've managed to ***cognitize*** the word!

I googled it and *yes* it has begun to be used.

Some aren't what I was looking for, because the word is used as a causative, e.g. "[Cognitize your course: Technology tools to optimize cognition in online learning](https://www.learntechlib.org/primary/p/177852)" and "[Everything that we formerly electrified we will now cognitize.](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/future-of-artificial-intelligence/)"

But some are, e.g.:

- [Technologies that **cognitize** with us, thus playing an active part in
  our cognitive processes and constituting themselves as inherent
  components in human …](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=IN_22nUU_BMC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22cognitize%22&source=bl&ots=mXlZvnqufH&sig=-ggTMeVyZjLTHEmTexS-V5SBJmg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif6tfcjeLcAhXSbSsKHfiJATc4ChDoATACegQICBAB)
- [Therefore, in the process of young children's attempt in applying their limited vocabulary to map objects in the real world, non- extendedness, the unmarked extension, would appear to be easier to perceive, **cognitize** and acquire than the …](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=eh0IAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cognitize%22&dq=%22cognitize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipu7yAoOjgAhUKMY8KHaeWCLAQ6AEIPjAE)
- [Tanner and Lupton133 have probed into the constructs which engineers may use and have made a useful start on the process of discovering how industrial engineers in different enterprises (and countries) **cognitize** the zones of manoeuvre.](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=QOW1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22cognitize%22&dq=%22cognitize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipu7yAoOjgAhUKMY8KHaeWCLAQ6AEIQjAF)

Someone on FB also asked: [*is there a word called "cognitize"*](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=172562899599570&id=166054823583711)

[Update: I'm super-duper happy to find much greater confirmation as shown in Sven Yargs's comment below. **41 confirmed unique matches for *cognitize*, 2 for *de-cognitize*, and 31 for *cognitise***, is super good enough for me.]

Thanks, everybody for the conversation. Although none of you provided this word, you've made me ***cognitize*** enough to have this word come up in my head.

[Update: You may be interested to see this on Google's Ngram Viewer: [cognitize](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cognitize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccognitize%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The sources which you have provided are not reliable. [Here](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=YhvB9D7vxGQC&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=%22cognitize%22&source=bl&ots=LyTqPKQqYV&sig=0hluIbIqAKd1FmULtm6FSwDUTAc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgrZiukOLcAhUBVH0KHZUyDg04FBDoATAHegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=%22cognitize%22&f=false) it is used metaphorically to that of  magnetize.

Comment: Accept the change. Your answer looks like hotchpotch.

Comment: I didn't reject it. When I took a look, it was already rejected. I agree that it looks better now.

Comment: You need to accept second change also for the last link.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the number next to "edit". I think I earlier accidentally rejected your edit. Sorry.

Comment: +1. A [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cognitize%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) returns 41 confirmed unique matches for _cognitize_ (one from 1911 and all of the rest from 1964 or later) and 2 for _de-cognitize_ (from 1973 and 2002) . A second [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=t-V5W5G5Kovc8APz2ZHoDw&q=%22cognitise%22&oq=%22cognitise%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...2453.2453.0.4396.1.1.0.0.0.0.56.56.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.TosXBruvyPI) finds an additional 31 confirmable unique matches for _cognitise_ (all since 1978).

Comment: Oh, wow! I didn't think of doing that. Thanks a lot, Sven. Well, I think this makes it reasonable to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The word ***cognize*** (*cognise*) does exist, but according to the OED etymology it seems a relatively recent word backformed from *cognisant*, *cognition* etc. and from the earlier *recognise*.
The relevant entry is:

> Etymology: A comparatively modern word, formed with reference to
>   cognizance , cognizor , and the kindred words, and the earlier
>   recognize . It thus corresponds analogically, but not phonetically, to
>   Latin cognōscere , Old French conoistre , French connaître : compare
>   cognosce v. The prevalence of the ending -ize over -ise is apparently
>   due to the influence of the large class of verbs having etymological
>   -ize suffix.
>
> †1. Law. (intr. or absol.) To take cognizance. 1659   T. Burton
>   Diary (1828) III. 129   The Judges..sit at Westminster, and they
>   cognize.
>
> 2. trans. To take cognizance of, take note of, notice, observe. 1821   Joseph the Book-man 107   [He] was cogniz'd by every eye.
>
> 1889   J. M. Robertson Ess. Crit. Method 72   Moved to incipient
>   hysteria where anon I should simply cognize pathos.
>
> 3. Philosophy. To know, perceive, become conscious of; to make (anything) an object of cognition.
>
> a1856   W. Hamilton Lect. Metaphysics (1859) II. xxi. 19   It would
>   also be convenient..for psychological precision and emphasis, to use
>   the word to cognise in connection with its noun cognition.
>
> a1856   W. Hamilton Lect. Metaphysics (1859) II. xxxvi. 329   They
>   first know,—they first cognise, the things and persons presented to
>   them.
>
> 1862   H. Spencer First Princ. i. iv. §24. 80   It is a material
>   object, and it is cognized by being recognized as such.
>
> 1876   St. G. Mivart Lessons from Nature vii. 196   We cognize an
>   object..by one act; we cognize that cognition by a very different act.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that ***drives me round the bend***. [From there] Here is a perfectly good entry from the OED, and it receives two downvotes. I have never seen in in modern speech or writing. That is not to say one cannot use it. After all, it is in the OED.

Comment: Got a hint from your answer. I see ”take cognizance“. Aha! In the same way, I can say "to have cognition"!

Answer (score 0):

**[cognize](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cognize)**

> or **cognise** (ˈkɒɡnaɪz , kɒɡˈnaɪz )
>   verb
>   *(transitive)*
>   to perceive, become aware of, or know
>   <sup>*Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins*</sup>

See also:

> *‘The distinction between intuitive and abstractive cognition does not depend on the object at all; the very same object can be cognized in both an intuitive and an abstractive way.’*
>   (**[cognize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cognize)** on ODO)

Comment: Well spotted, +1. I've learned a new word, but I have no idea when I'll use it, if I slipped it into conversation with my friends and family I suspect that I'd be subjected to derision rather than respect. Ah well, what's new?

Comment: @BoldBen It's a formal word. Better suited for scholarly writing. I don't think it can "be slipped it into conversation with friends and family" without being "subjected to derision rather than respect." But that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks, but _cognize_ seems more like the verb for ***cognizance***, right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **cognite** is not a word. There is no apparent entry of this word in any of the standard dictionaries. So, there is no question of it being a verb.

That said, you are right, that **cognize or cognise** *does not fully cover the meaning of* **cognition** **because** **cognize is a** [verb](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cognize) **of cognizance**.

But, you can still use *cognize* as a verb for *cognition* ***on selected topics*** where cognition **acts as a noun** for cognizance, check below.

There are delineating **similarities** between Cognition (noun) and Cognizance (noun) which allows us to use "***cognize***" as a **verb** to ***cognition***.

**Following are the details**:

[image]

So, **whenever cognition acts as a noun to cognizance you can use "cognize" as verb to cognition**.

Why, **cogitate** can't be used as **verb** for **cognition**?

[image]

Comment: There are some grammatical mistakes in your source, which doesn't necessarily make the information wrong, but I'd find it less trustworthy for this reason. Where is it from?

Comment: Yes, where is it from? I like the answer though, and am considering marking it as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks. You need to remove/change the last character (]) for the correct link.

Comment: @KumāraBhikkhu yep! done already. If you like the answer, then don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @KumāraBhikkhu can I ask you, where you came across this thought of having verb for congnition?

Comment: It's because I want to translate a Pāli verb _manasikaroti_. I've decided that the correct translation for the noun _manasikāra_ is _cognition_. Therefore.

Comment: @KumāraBhikkhu "cognitize" is a neologism. You might use it, if you provide reference in your work. Secondly, it is not standard word. So, many people will not recognise it. Use it wisely.

Answer (score -1):

***Cognition***,  in the sense of "perception, sensation" is an old usage dating back to the 17th century:

> ***In 17c. the meaning was extended to include perception and sensation.***

from which:

> the psychological processes by which individuals acquire and process information, generally applied to thought processes and memory. cognitive psychology the branch of psychology concerned with the study of cognition.

(Dictionary of Sport and Exercise Science and Medicine by Churchill Livingstone)

The verb is [cognize](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cognize). The originale term from which all other related term derive is cognizance, from Old French “conoistre” (to know). Note that it is a formal term.

> "***perceive, become conscious of***," 1650s, back-formation from [cognizance](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cognizance?ref=etymonline_crossreference). The French word is connaître (Old French conoistre).

(Etymonline)

Comment: Cognizance and cognition are not same thing.

Comment: @ubihatt - I didn't say they are. I am talking about their original root.